# Fetch from MySQL to jquery (mobil app) through PHP (jQuery/AJAX)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have seen many tutorials, but they're so confusing, and to do what I want to do, I just don't get how to use existing stuff from those tutorials and make them work they way I want them to.

I have an icon @homepage . when the users clicks that ,i would like do a query "select * from tablename", and display the result in a particular div .

Can someone please show me how this can be achieved? Just something very basic is all i'm after to get me started. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you have any particular questions?

Comment: I suggest reading the faq before posting questions.

Comment: i hate to ask every time, have you tried something, please post the code

Comment: since this is his first post, you guys shouldn't be so hard on him. Try this tutorial and edit your question telling us how did it go: http://www.askaboutphp.com/213/php-and-jquery-submit-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page.html

Comment: @luchosrock we're aware of that, but we cv and downvote because this really isn't fit for SO (though i can see a few improvements that could make this question worthwhile). The sheer volume of *"this is my first question; I haven't even tried to solve my problem or I wont show you anything, I just want a crystal ball answer or a documentation link"*-type questions in the [tag:php] tag is astonishingly high. So yes, we **should** be hard on him (or her).

Comment: @Hiroto good point. Maybe he/she should have seen the big rectangle on the right side of the question form and read the faq, so we give him/her such a warm welcome

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(function() {
    $("#buttonId#).click(function() {
        $("#divToUpdate").load("/scriptPhp.php");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="buttonId" type="button" value="click me!" />
<br />
<div id="divToUpdate">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in your scriptPHP.php file:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Cell 1</th>
            <th>Cell 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
$pdo = new Pdo("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nameOfTheDatabase;charset=utf8", "username", "password");

$rows = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tablename")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['cell_1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cell_2']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

the documentation pretty much explains its self: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 1;");
while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) != NULL) {
  //use rows
}
$mysqli->close();
```